# Unable to capture image every 5 seconds using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to capture image in every 5 seconds using opencv through my laptop's built-in webcam. I am using time.sleep(5) for the required pause. In every run, the first image seems to be correctly saved but after that rest all the images are being saved as an unsupported format (when i am opening them). Also I am unable to break the loop by pressing 'q'.
Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
framerate = cap.get(5)
x=1

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()
    # Our operations on the frame come here



    filename = 'C:/Users/shjohari/Desktop/Retail_AI/MySection/to_predict/image' +  str(int(x)) + ".png"
    x=x+1
    cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
    time.sleep(5)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change, solved my issue.
I included the below code inside the loop :P

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
framerate = cap.get(5)
```